# Python requests accepting terms and conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to access a website and I can not accept the terms and conditions to make the request that I want to.

Here is my code,

```
import cfscrape
site = "https://tr.0day.today/search"
kw = input("Search: ")
class zero_day:
    def ara(self):
        with cfscrape.create_scraper() as s:
            payloads = {
                "search_requests":kw}
            r = s.get(site)
            r = s.post(site, data=payloads)
            print(r.text)

zero_day = zero_day()
zero_day.ara()
```

And when I run this script, it returns the page of "do you accept terms and conditions". How can I access the page that I want?

Comment: Just use the developer tools in your browser to see what requests it's making when you do the same thing there.  Probably a POST request.

Comment: Isn't this a case where Selenium is needed?

Comment: Can anyone please provide an example of how to automatically accept the terms and conditions. I have the same problem and still cannot solve the problem. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://planning.ashford.gov.uk/buildingControl/Default.aspx?new=true')
agree = driver.find_element_by_id("CPH_Details_Agree_CheckBox")
submit = driver.find_element_by_id("CPH_Details_Submit_Button")
agree.click()
submit.click()
```

You can find the reference to the agreement box by going to more tools -> developer tools and then search for something similar to that.

Comment: (Congratulations on the obligation to pay this groundbreaking washing machine.  - looks good otherwise)